# a0poster: Poster second column not starting from beginning of a page but shifted down

Tags: posters, a0poster, tikz-node

I am making my first poster with the use of `a0poster` package, based on code I forked from [rOpenGov poster repo](https://github.com/rOpenGov/poster).

I have a problem with editing the second column of a content: the first `node` is shifted down and seems to be *fixed* that way - if I add additional content that is supposed to fill the whole right column below the title, the first `node` does not move up, but the whole content is moved to second page (stays no longer above the title), with this first `node` in the right column still shifted down in the same manner.

What I am doing wrong?

- first right column node definition:

  ```
  \tikzstyle{myboxwhite} = [rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=0pt, inner ysep=0pt]
  ```

  and its implementation:

  ```
  \node [myboxwhite, yshift=0cm, xshift=40cm] (fvillustration){%

    \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}

    text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem 

    \end{minipage}
  };
  ```
- full .Rmd file (**reproducible example**): [link](https://github.com/statsox/Penalized-Regression-Inference/blob/master/repr/poster-cpy-repr.Rnw)
- PDF output screen:

[image]

Comment: Can you give the code for a simple example that can be immediately compiled by someone trying to replicate your problem (without trying to guess at your setup)?

Comment: Dear @Emma, thank you very much for your interest! You are right, I edited my question, providing a link to reproducible example (.Rnw file one can compile without any external files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shift to the second page is a symptom of the first problem: filling the whole second column shifts all of the content to the second page because the `tikzpicture` no longer all fits on the first page with the title, as you have two full-length columns which are offset.

This offset occurs because it is vertically aligning the middle of the new box with the middle of the intro box and then placing the remaining boxes in each column relative to those. To align a box with the top of `intro` you can add as arguments `right=40 cm of intro.north, anchor=north` (in place of `right of=intro, node distance=40cm`), which places the top middle of the new box 40cm to the right of the top middle of the intro box.

You could also use a similar idea to specify the space between boxes in a column, e.g., `below=1cm of intro.south, anchor=north` places the top of the new box 1cm below the bottom of the intro. The way you are doing it now specifies the distance between the centers of the boxes, so it requires you to manually adjust the distance depending on the box sizes.

Comment: I couldn't appreciate your answer more! `right=40 cm of intro.north, anchor=north` works perfectly well, and the solution you suggested in 3rd paragraph (`below=1cm of intro.south, anchor=north`) simplifies my work greatly. Thank you very much!